# Accessing tabular data via hyperlinks with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

There's something I still don't understand about using BeautifulSoup. I can use this to parse the raw HTML of a webpage, here "example_website.com":

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # load BeautifulSoup class
import requests 
r  = requests.get("http://example_website.com")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
# soup.find_all('a') grabs all elements with <a> tag for hyperlinks
```

Then, to retrieve and print all elements with the 'href' attribute, we can use a for loop:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

What I don't understand: I have a website with several webpages, and each webpage lists several hyperlinks to a single webpage with tabular data.

I can use BeautifulSoup to parse the homepage, but how do I use the same Python script to scrape page 2, page 3, and so on? How do you "access" the contents found via the 'href' links?

Is there a way to write a python script to do this? Should I be using a spider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `requests`+`BeautifulSoup` for sure. It would be of a blocking nature, since you would process the extracted links one by one and you would not proceed to the next link until you are done with the current. Sample implementation:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests 

with requests.Session() as session:    
    r = session.get("http://example_website.com")
    data = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

    base_url = "http://example_website.com" 
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        url = urljoin(base_url, link.get('href'))

        r = session.get(url)
        # parse the subpage
```

Though, it may quickly get complex and slow.

You may need to switch to [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](http://scrapy.org/) which makes web-scraping, crawling, following the links easy (check out [`CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) with link extractors), fast and in a non-blocking nature (it is based on Twisted).

Comment: "complex and slow" That's the problem. I think I would have to process the links one by one. For a "directory" type website (think Yelp, for example), this gets tedious. You would have to write multiple for loops, and make sure you're not skipping anything. (I could be wrong!)